# Vectors and matrices in Python 3.x

Tags: python, vector, matrix, python-3.x

Is there a good Python 3 library for vectors and matrices?

Here's some of the functionality I expect to find in such a library:

- matrix multiplication
- matrix determinant
- euclidean distance between two vectors
- cosine similarity between two vectors
- convolution

Comment: Why do you need to use python3? Just use 2.6 with numpy.

Comment: @Falmarri: I don't need, I want. Python 3 is better than Python 2 except the lack of a good mathematical library.

Comment: Why 2.6 given this: http://www.mail-archive.com/numpy-discussion@scipy.org/msg26524.html

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The 1.5 version of [numpy](http://numpy.org/) is compatible with Python 3.

Answer (score 1):

U can download numpy for python 3: http://sourceforge.net/projects/numpy/files/NumPy/1.5.1/numpy-1.5.1-win32-superpack-python3.1.exe/download

Its the best tool in the python for world for what u need